# ExtJs manually firing Click event, button param is different from mouse click

Tags: javascript, extjs

So, I have a login controller, you can click login with mouse or press Enter key, like this:

```
Ext.define('My.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "#idLogin button": {click: this.onButton},
            "#idLogin form > *": {specialkey: this.onKey}
        });
    },

    onButton: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var win = button.up('window'); // the login window
        //do more stuff...
    },

    onKey: function (field, el) {
        if (el.getKey() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER) //ENTER key performs Login
            Ext.getCmp('#idLogin button').fireEvent('click');
    }
});
```

I realised when I use the mouse to click the Login button, `onButton` function works properly, `button.up()` returns me the Login `window`.

However, if I pressed Enter key and fires the `onKey` function to do `fireEvent('click')`, in this case the `onButton` fires up but parameter `button` NOT the same as the `button` parameter received when you click by mouse! And this time, `button.up()` function is undefined.

Question is, why does `fireEvent('click')` give me a different button parameter?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must use the `fireEvent` function like that:

```
var myBtn = Ext.getCmp('#idLogin button');

myBtn.fireEvent('click', myBtn);
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you :D spot on and very fast@!

Comment: why there is no `button.click()` ?

Answer (score 8):

Because the button click event is a synthetic event fired by the framework. It passes along the button instance and an event object. `fireEvent` means "notify any subscribers that this event has happened, with these arguments", not "trigger a click event on the underlying button".

So you'd need to use:

`button.fireEvent('click', button);`

However, this doesn't really make sense, you're just adding an extra layer of indirection.

Why not abstract it out:

```
Ext.define('My.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "#idLogin button": {click: this.onButton},
            "#idLogin form > *": {specialkey: this.onKey}
        });
    },

    onButton: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        this.doWindowFoo();
    },

    onKey: function (field, el) {
        if (el.getKey() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER) //ENTER key performs Login
            this.doWindowFoo();
    },

    doWindowFoo: function() {
        // Assumes the window has an id idLogin, there are several other ways to get a reference
        var win = Ext.getCmp('idLogin');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! Indianer beat it by 60 seconds with a short one XD

Comment: The answer is "wrong", you shouldn't be firing an event on the button. It is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: EvanT, it is not nice to take the 'accept' back from him XD but i agree you have gone deeper into restructuring the functions in best practice. You have flatten down the layers. I wish I could give u 10+ Cheers!~

Comment: I don't really care about the accepted answer, just pointing out that you shouldn't use that approach in your own code.

Comment: how to do it with native js?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
var button= Ext.getCmp('#idLogin button');    
button.fireHandler();
```

Comment: "fireHandler" is a private function, and should not be relied on:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-fireHandler

Answer (score 1):

this will call the handler function in your button, in my case it worked, due i override that button handler with additional functionality and parameters value changes...(extjs 4.1.1)

```
Ext.getCmp('#idLogin button').handler();
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general way:

```
document.querySelector("what-ever-el-selector").click();
```

Tested on extjs 4.2.6

Cheers