# Programmatically call handler of a button event?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

How can I call a handler from an button event? I want to click event a button and call that button handler?

```
Ext.getCmp('buttonID').click();
/// How to fire handler of that button?
```

Comment: Put your handler logic into a method and call that method...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145882/extjs-manually-firing-click-event-button-param-is-different-from-mouse-click

Comment: @CodeWhisperer It seems that this question is about triggering the button handler, while the one you link is about firing the `click` event.

Comment: But the handler would be triggered after a `click` event no?

Comment: No, not in Ext5 at least. The [fireHandler](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/source/Button.html#Ext-button-Button-method-fireHandler) method that I've linked to bellow will fire the click event first, and then only the handler (if no click listeners returned false).

Comment: How would you use it?

Answer (score 4):

You may get this way:

```
var button = Ext.getCmp('buttonID'); 
button.fireEvent('click', button);
```

The second param must be `button` if you want to keep hanlder logic equals to common button's clicking

Answer (score 2):

Ext itself does it [this way](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/source/Button.html#Ext-button-Button-method-fireHandler):

```
var btn = Ext.getCmp('buttonID');
var e = null; // we don't have any event, so let's use nothing
Ext.callback(btn.handler, btn.scope, [btn, e], 0, btn);
```

If your handler depends on the event, it will not work...

Comment: Here's my button <img role="button" alt="" src="button.jpg">

Comment: Oh I see. I'm sorry dude, but your Ext5 button is actually a HTML image. You should bring it back to the seller...