# How to fire an click event on the "OK" of Ext.Msg.alert?

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6-classic

After a form is saved successfully, an alert is fired and looks as the following:

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Success','Changes saved successfully');
```

[image]

How to fire an `click event` on the "OK" through `javascript` or `extjs`?

Refer to [Programmatically call handler of a button event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834028/programmatically-call-handler-of-a-button-event?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), the following worked, however it looks a bad idea to find out the `button-id` that is generated by `extjs`.

```
var btn = Ext.getCmp('button-id');
var e = null; // we don't have any event, so let's use nothing
Ext.callback(btn.handler, btn.scope, [btn, e], 0, btn);
```

Comment: This article talks about intercepting the window close by clicking the X icon, but I'm pretty sure you can use this to do the same thing for the OK button (http://existdissolve.com/2011/08/extjs-4-intercepting-a-window-closure/)

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you need ?

Comment: @N.Jadhav updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go down the component hierarchy from `Ext.Msg` (or whatever none-singleton instance of message box you are using). In ExtJS 6 classic, the way to go would be:

```
Ext.Msg.down('button[itemId=ok]').click();
```

I have made a small fiddle that shows [the working solution](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hgg).

Answer (score 1):

First whenever you will show [`Ext.Msg.alert()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.window.MessageBox.html#property-OK) store in variable like this

```
var msg = Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Changes save successfully')
```

Then after you can get ok button using [`msg.down('#ok')`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.window.MessageBox.html#property-OK), this will return `OK` button. And button have method to `fireHandler()` so you can use that to call handler pro-grammatically.

In this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2hgk), I have created a demo.

**Note** I have used `Ext.defer` function to fire handler after 3s. You can change based on your requirement whenever you want to fire this.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var msg = Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Changes save successfully', function (btn) {
            if (btn == "ok") {
                console.log(btn);
            }
        });

        //Defer is just only for demo
        //You can put your logic based on requirement
        //I am just giving example of how to fire the event
        Ext.defer(function () {
            var buttonOk = msg.down('#ok')
            buttonOk.fireHandler(buttonOk);
        }, 3000);

    }
});
```

Comment: Alexander's answer is better for it doesn't need a var to track it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is woking code to capture OK button click event:

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Name', 'Please enter your name:', function(btn, text){
    if (btn == 'ok'){
        console.log("OK clicked");
        // you code here
    }
});
```

Here is working demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVojEX?editors=0010

Comment: The code can not be added within the Ext.Msg.alert, since it's used in other case too

Comment: @caot what do you mean?